# Open Source Epub reader like Booki.sh

Tags: javascript, epub, epub3, monocle

I want to create a epub reader for my website, So I need an open source solution for it. I found lots of things but I don't know what is the best one for me. Please help me. Recently I goto the https://booki.sh/library and it's prety cool. I'm looking for something like booki.sh epub reader.

Thanks

Comment: Try coding, define your requirements, and get back to Stack Overflow if you are stuck with coding.

Answer (score 4):

If I might suggest [Readium](http://readium.org/) as it has a strong community and support from some major players. While it has native libraries for building to iOS, Android, OSX, and Windows, it's coolest new feature is [Readium.js](https://github.com/readium/readium-js) with which you could likely build your web viewer. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes I found it also, but it's documentation page is not working now.
[Documentation](http://github.readium.org/docs/ebook.html)

Comment: Yes, in a strange twist they've moved all there docs to Google Docs here: [Documents about Readium SDK on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/?hl=en&pli=1#folders/0BzaNaBNAB6FjbU90WlhGR2lDOXM) and as far as Docs for the JS library they're in the repo [here](https://github.com/readium/readium/tree/master/docs)

Comment: there is futurepress/epub.js (reading epub and annotation through a browner)